# JavaScript Draw in a Canvas Disappear After Setting crossOrigin as Anonymous

Tags: javascript, download

I am currently doing a javascript function that draws in an HTML canvas by doing some drawing inside of it AND loading an image from another website.

Everything was working fine until I needed to create a function to download it. At first, I was getting a security error because I didn't set the crossOrigin of the image I was loading as anonymous so I did. And then I was able to download the image. However, it made the image that I loaded in the canvas from the other website disappear. Any idea why?

Here is my function to download:

```
  function download(){
   var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas0");
   $("#btn-download").on("click",(e)=>{
   var data = canvas.toDataURL("data:image/png;");
   var btn=document.getElementById("btn-download");
   btn.href=data;
   btn.download="Canvas.png";
 });
}
```

And here is where I load the image and set the crossOrigin as anonymous.

```
img=new Image();
img.onload = function() {
 context.drawImage(img, 285, 160);
};
img.src = 'somelink';
img.crossOrigin = "anonymous"
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Cœur apologies, I didn't realize that was a problem. I'll stop

Comment: @codeforever No problem, we can always get assistance by asking Quack Overflow.

Comment: @Cœur Bless that little bird.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after a lot of thinking, i realized that when the website was giving me the image, the Access-Control-Allow-Origin wasn't in the header SO it was impossible to avec the crossOrigin to anonymous.
If you have this problem, check in your console if the header has Access-Control-Allow-Origin or not.